Preserving/correcting outdated saved overlays in edited file via diff?
I want to create overlays and save them to a file to be loaded later:

One issue I ran into is that sometimes if I forget to save the overlays, I load overlays whose position is outdated for the current file. I thought that using a save-hook would be enough, but unfortunately there were many other cases where this also broke, such as VC changing branches or the file being edited externally.
For example, let's say I changed my file:

Loading the overlay now looks like

which is bad.
I've came up with the idea of attempting to patch the overlays by also saving the original state of the file in question, along with the overlays; now, when the file is out-of-date, I will revert the file momentarily to its original form, apply the overlays (now they are guaranteed to be in their correct positions) and then call insert and delete-region in such a way that my file is recreated to its updated state. In theory, this should preserve the correct positions for the overlays.
The problem is I'm not sure how to do this. diff/ediff/smerge don't seem to offer this kind of functionality, and I was hoping something exists so that I wouldn't have to reinvent it. More so, I hope that this is an XY problem, and that there is a better solution for correcting overlays.

I would consider making use of the existing concept of bookmarks, which attempt to adapt to file changes in much the same way as diffs/patches, by including some surrounding context along with the position (see also bookmark-search-size).  The position can then be adjusted, if the context is located elsewhere.  It's not a guarantee, of course, so it depends on how robust you need it to be.  See bookmark-default-handler for how the context strings are specifically used (by default).

Also see https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AnnotationMode and https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/cvfudo/i_finally_found_an_annotation_library_the_works/ which I think are doing something similar to your code?

The wiki page has reminded me that bookmarks already include an "annotations" feature -- you can associate arbitrary text with any bookmark, and that gets saved to the bookmark file as well.  By default the ways of displaying this do not bear any resemblance to your overlays, but one could certainly write code to do that.

The other annotation libraries I've looked at just now do have some protection against files changing unexpectedly, but only via checksums to ensure the user knows there's a mismatch.  I'm not sure anything else is attempting to automatically resolve the differences.

I came up with my own solution to bend Ediff to work programmatically. Using the answer (and its comment) from here, I wrote the following brittle function:
(defun wordwise-diff-patch-buffers (old new)
  "Wordwise patch buffer OLD to be equivalent to buffer NEW via `ediff-buffers'.

This is mostly a brittle hack meant to make Ediff be used noninteractively."
  (cl-labels ((apply-all-diffs ()
                (ediff-next-difference)
                (while (ediff-valid-difference-p)
                  (ediff-copy-B-to-A nil)
                  (ediff-next-difference))))
    (let ((orig-window-config (current-window-configuration)))
      (unwind-protect
          (progn
            (let ((old-region (with-current-buffer old
                                (cons (point-min) (point-max))))
                  (new-region (with-current-buffer new
                                (cons (point-min) (point-max)))))
              ;; The following two bindings prevent Ediff from creating a new window.
              (let ((ediff-window-setup-function 'ediff-setup-windows-plain)
                    (ediff-split-window-function 'split-window-horizontally))
                ;; Run wordwise diff first to replace with higher granularity.
                (ediff-regions-internal old
                                        (car old-region)
                                        (cdr old-region)
                                        new
                                        (car new-region)
                                        (cdr new-region)
                                        nil
                                        (gensym "ediff-")
                                        t
                                        nil)
                (cl-letf (((symbol-function 'y-or-n-p) (lambda (&rest _) t)))
                  ;; This is very brittle.
                  (with-current-buffer (get-buffer "*Ediff Control Panel*")
                    (apply-all-diffs)
                    (ediff-quit t))
                  ;; Run regular diff to also replace empty newlines.
                  (ediff-buffers old new)
                  (with-current-buffer (get-buffer "*Ediff Control Panel*")
                    (apply-all-diffs)
                    (ediff-quit t))))))
        (set-window-configuration orig-window-config)))))

Issues:

Uses brittle buffer name for the Ediff control panel buffer, whose commands only work if you are inside it.
Uses an internal Ediff function. If I use the exposed one, then I am entered into a recursive editing mode, which I cannot control programmatically.

